# Setting up Visual Studio 2013 to Develop AutoCAD 2015 plugins

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autocad-plugin, objectarx

I'm trying to continue working on my plugins for AutoCAD in Visual Studio 2013. I opened up my project files and all the references to Autodesk libraries were missing. To remedy this, I added references to the following dll files from ObjectARX 2015 shown in the dlls image attached. I am using the following Autodesk namespaces:

```
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;
```

Adding the missing references makes the errors go away until I try to test my program at which point I get new errors underlining Autodesk references in gray instead of red as shown in the attached image. I have no idea why the added references are not working. It may also be worth knowing I've migrated from Visual Studio 2012 to Visual Studio 2013 and AutoCAD 2014 to AutoCAD 2015[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm unsure why they have that gray line under them.  Are yout setting your copy local setting to false for those references? Or do you have multiple auto cad libraries of different autocad versions in your references? BTW I don't see any reason you should have all of those references. You should only need runtime for what you have in your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your target .NET framework. If the Dll's that you are referencing are built for 4.0 you need to target 4.0. If they are built for 4.5 you need to target 4.5.

Here are the steps to change the target framework if you don't know how.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx